# single core vs multicore LV power cables

Tags: cables, ups

For a three-phase UPS system of 400 V, disregarding the cost, is it better to install for 3 phases plus 1 neutral plus 1 ground

1. five single-core cables.
2. One 3-C cable plus two cables each is 1-C.
3. One 4-C cable plus one 1-C cable.

The cables are all in one big room.

Space is not a problem.

the input cables will go from a circuit breaker to the UPS.

the output cables will go from the UPS to a circuit breaker.

Comment: please define `better`

Comment: It's best to follow the guidelines in the instruction manual with the proviso that the device is legal, is bought through a reputable dealer and that the original manufacturer has a decent quality system.

Comment: Whether you can use a multicondutcor cable must use individual conductors will depend on current requirements and the local electrical code or other wiring practices.

Comment: @jsotola better in the sense, it would least problems i.e. more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

All four conductors have to be in the same cable.  The reason is you are dealing with AC power, and they are throwing considerable electro-magnetic fields. Allowing the conductors to be separated "turns everything between them into the core of a transformer".

Since these magnetic fields are rapidly changing, this can cause vibration between the conductors leading to metal fatigue, cracking, loss of wire cross-section, localized heating, arcing, and fire.

Also, it will cause eddy-current heating in anything *metallic* between the conductors, such as a cable staple or enclosure hardware (hence rule 300.20).

See [this link](http://www.mikeholt.com/download.php?file=PDF/Standby_Power_Systems_Part_4.pdf), page (document) 97 at "I", and page 105 at "300.20".

Current does not normally move on safety ground / earth, so it is not subject to the "same cable" rule; however other construction codes such as the UL White Book may require this too.

Note also that non-flexible metal-shell conduit is often considered a valid earthing path. Flexible metal conduits vary, depending on the design of the flex joints.